# Refining the dataframe according to words list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a word list of type `list` containing large number of English words.

I also have a dataframe which looks like:-

```
    FileName        PageNo     LineNo   GOODS_DESC  
1   17743633 - 1    TM000002    69      Abuj Cen Le 
31  17743633 - 1    TM000007    126     Mr USD  
33  17743633 - 1    TM000008    22      TABLEAU EMBALLAGE
34  17743633 - 1    TM000008    24      LISA e EMBALV
46  17743633 - 1    TM000008    143     Cen 
47  17743633 - 1    TM000008    146     A Gl
50  17743633 - 1    TM000009    121     Ppvv Tn Ppvv In 
51  17743633 - 1    TM000009    129     SPECIFY
52  17743633 - 1    TM000009    136     Decrp G 
58  17743633 - 1    TM000009    97      Je ugn  
60  17743633 - 1    TM000009    108     De Veel 
61  17743633 - 1    TM000014    44      TYRE CHIPS SHREDDED TYRES   
63  17743633 - 1    TM000014    48      TYRE CHIPS SHREDDED TYRES
```

I want to keep only those words in the 'GOODS_DESC' column that are present in the words list.

My desired output is:-

```
    FileName        PageNo     LineNo   GOODS_DESC  
1   17743633 - 1    TM000002    69      NaN
31  17743633 - 1    TM000007    126     Mr USD  
33  17743633 - 1    TM000008    22      TABLEAU
34  17743633 - 1    TM000008    24      LISA  
46  17743633 - 1    TM000008    143     NaN 
47  17743633 - 1    TM000008    146     NaN
50  17743633 - 1    TM000009    121     NaN 
51  17743633 - 1    TM000009    129     SPECIFY
52  17743633 - 1    TM000009    136     NaN
58  17743633 - 1    TM000009    97      NaN 
60  17743633 - 1    TM000009    108     NaN
61  17743633 - 1    TM000014    44      TYRE CHIPS SHREDDED TYRES   
63  17743633 - 1    TM000014    48      TYRE CHIPS SHREDDED TYRES
```

My approach is also giving output but I'm using lists and it is slow. I want to make it fast.

```
for rows in df.itertuples():
    a = []
    flat_list = []
    a.append(rows.GOODS_DESC)
    flat_list = [item.strip() for sublist in a for item in sublist.split(' ') if item.strip()]
    flat_list = list(sorted(set(flat_list), key=flat_list.index))
    flat_list = [i for i in flat_list if i.lower() in word_list]
    if(not flat_list):
        df.drop(rows.Index,inplace=True)
        continue
    s=' '.join(flat_list)
    df.loc[rows.Index,'GOODS_DESC']=s

df['GOODS_DESC'] = df['GOODS_DESC'].str.upper()
```

Comment: Where's your word list?

Comment: from nltk.corpus import words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic seems overly complicated. You can use a single list comprehension with `pd.Series.apply`. I recommend, as below, you use `set` for O(1) lookup and `str.casefold` to match strings irrespective of case.

```
s = pd.Series(['Abuj Cen Le', 'Mr USD', 'TABLEAU EMBALLAGE', 'LISA e EMBALV'])

word_set = {i.casefold() for i in ['Mr', 'USD', 'TABLEAU', 'LISA']}

def apply_filter(x):
    out = ' '.join([i for i in x.split() if i.casefold() in word_set])
    return out if out else np.nan

res = s.apply(apply_filter)

print(res)

0        NaN
1     Mr USD
2    TABLEAU
3       LISA
dtype: object
```

Comment: this code is working fine but not helping my cause of reducing time duration :(

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `merge` and `join` to do what you want. First some preparation:

```
#input file, you can have any number of columns in it
df_input = pd.DataFrame({'col1':range(1,5),
                         'GOODS_DESC':['Abuj Cen Le', 'Mr USD', 
                                       'TABLEAU EMBALLAGE', 'LISA e EMBALV']})
# DF from the list of words
df_word = pd.DataFrame({'Word':[word.lower() for word in word_list]})
# create a df_stack with each word of your sentences as a row keeping indexes for join later
df_stack = (df_input['GOODS_DESC'].str.split(' ',expand=True).stack().reset_index())
# Column with same name as df_word and lowercase for merge after
df_stack['Word'] = df_stack[0].str.lower()
```

Now you can use `merge` and then `join`:

```
df_join = df_stack.merge(df_word).groupby('level_0')[0].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
df_output = df_input.join(df_join)
# get ride
df_output = df_output.drop('GOODS_DESC',1).rename(columns={0:'GOODS_DESC'})
```

It looks like a lot of lines, but `merge` and `join` are efficient so I hope it will be fast enough.